# Build models in h2o flow in windows, use on an AIX server? Help for a non-programmer

Tags: h2o

I'm hoping someone can give me some advise for taking models built in h2o flow on a windows machine and exporting/using them on an AIX server.

I've been able to use the flow graphical interface to build some models. I'm not a java coder / programmer so have some trouble understanding the instructions on the pojo/mojo files in the documentation and really looking for some step-by-step help on using them.

I have h2o running on a windows desktop machine. The place I want to use it is within SAS programs running on an AIX server. The AIX server has java.

I'm assuming I can do something like:

1. build model in h2o on my windows desktop
2. download the pojo or mojo files
3. do something????
4. put resulting file(s) from step 3 on the AIX server
5. use SAS to write out a CSV file in the same format I used to build the model in h2o
6. use SAS to issue unix command line statements that feed the .csv file into the exported files from step 3 using java and generate a new output .csv file with scored records
7. read the scores back into my SAS program and continue on my way

Is this do-able?

If not, can someone give me a "for dummies" explanation of how I might do something similar? I don't have admin rights on the AIX server so can't install software.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it's technically possible to do this, but it's not been done to my knowledge.  So unfortunately there is no "for dummies" explanation.  With AIX and SAS, your environment is veering far away from the standard open source environments with ready-made examples, so you may not get any canned suggestions from stackoverflow. If you have production use cases and are looking for a team to engage with, my best suggestion would be to contact sales@h2o.ai, describe your situation, and ask about enterprise support.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will reach out. 

Is the answer different if I were trying to create a command line statement on a windows machine instead of aix?

Comment: Since your use case looks kind of batch oriented, on a Windows machine you could use R or Python to script the process.

Comment: yeah, it is going to be a monthly file scored in batch. 

is there a simple way to do it without either? create a compiled command line program I can feed a csv into and get an scored csv out of?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use a compiled command-line program that will accept a CSV and output a CSV.  The h2o-genmodel.jar file contains a little example utility.  Look here:  https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/5718c3137d795efc834c4e504f3ae3267b0373c0/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/tools/PredictCsv.java#L381

Answer (score 0):

AIX is big endian and windows (intel) is little endian. So as far as I know the H2O model generated on windows will not directly work on AIX, I think there is some work needed in H2O to make that work. But you can host that model on a PowerVM linux box next to AIX on same power system if that helps. Because you can have a little endian Linux. 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power%20Systems/page/H2O%20Driverless%20AI%20for%20Data%20on%20IBM%20AIX